# Best free Java profiler on Mac

Tags: java, profiling, profiler

I was using YourKit before and it was working perfectly, but it's too expensive for my taste. Is there some free or open-source Java profiler for Mac that's working as well as YourKit?

Comment: IMHO, if you have a debugger that can be paused, you already have [the best tool for finding performance problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://visualvm.dev.java.net/docindex.html

Answer (score 1):

YourKit offers Early Access (EA) builds which do not require a purchase. The main thing it does well is aggregating run times in your results. If method a() just calls other methods but very little time is actually spent in it, it doesn't show up much in VisualVM, even if the methods a() calls spend lots of time.

Comment: YourKit is a very good product.